# tooltipster.js: My link disappeared

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

My links in the menu disappeared when I used class="tooltip":

```
<li><a href="index.html" class="tooltip" title="Tooltipstertest">Start</a></li>
```

Have a look:
http://www.habeck-dental.ch/neu/

There should be the word START in the menu. The tooltip works fine. Why can't I see the link?

Comment: Because the `.tooltip` class has `opacity: 0;`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a conflict with Bootstrap. You could force the `opacity` to `1` :

```
.tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Or you could choose to use the [default bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

If you want to make things clean and still using tooltipster, you can use a custom baked bootstrap :

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Here you can choose what you really want to use from bootstrap (in this case make sure to disable **Tooltips** javascript component). It will also make it lighter.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
"opacity: 1" works but I will also try the default tooltip later.